# What is the faster way to calculate number of duplicate rows present in Redshift Table

Tags: sql, count, duplicates, amazon-redshift

There are millions of record in table. And need to calculate number of duplicate rows present in my table in Redshift. I could achieve it by using below query,

```
select 
    sum(cnt) from (select <primary_key>
    , count(*)-1 as cnt 
from 
    table_name 
group by 
    <primary_key> having count(*)>1
```

1. Is there a faster way to achieve the same ?
2. Is there a way do achieve this in a single query without using subquery ?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you define "duplicate rows"? Do all columns need to be duplicates, or is there a column that contains a unique key that can identify a duplicate easier?

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following query:

```
SELECT Column_name, COUNT(*) Count_Duplicate
FROM Table_name
 GROUP BY Column_name
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

If the criteria of duplication is only repeating primary key then

`SELECT count(1)-count(distinct <primary_key>) FROM your_table`

would work, except if you have specified your column as primary key in Redshift (it doesn't enforce constraint but if you mark a column as primary key `count(distinct <primary_key>)` will return the same as `count(1)` **even if there are duplicate values** in this column